# How to use Jackson to Marshall a list of JSON objects that contain unknown number of KV paiirs

Tags: java, json, jackson

Lets say that you have a json array that looks as follows :

```
[
  {
    "id" : 1,
    "first_name" : "Jane",
    "last_name" : "Doe"
  },
  {
    "id" : 2,
    "first_name" : "John",
    "middle_name" : "Q",
    "last_name" : "Public",
    "birth_year" : 1971
  },
  {
    "id" : 3,
    "anonymous_user" : true,
    "crm_id" : "abc123"
   },
   {
    "id" : 4,
    "first_name" : "Albert",
    "last_name" : "Einstein",
    "profession" : "Scientist",
    "birth_year" : 1879,
    "e_equals_mc_squared" : true
  }
]
```

The goal is to use Jackson to marshal to POJO. My thinking is that I could have a class to contain each K,V pair .. something like :

```
public class myDataObject {
    private String key;
    private T value;

    ...
}
```

And maybe a container class for that :

```
public class myDataContainer {
   private ArrayList<myDataObject> dataList;

   ...
}
```

My question becomes what does marshaling that look like using jackson? There is no schema for the json, each json object can have an unspecified number of K,V pairs and the list of keys is also unspecified.

Does something like this work? Is this even the right approach?

```
ArrayList<myDataContainer> dataList = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, new TypeReference<ArrayList<myDataContainer>() {});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your JSON really is, is a list of maps - with Strings as keys and Objects as values.

So, using Jackson, you should be able to do:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Map<String, Object>> data = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<Map<String, Object>>>(){});
```